# Passing arguments to thymeleaf fragment gives error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

With Spring and Thymeleaf 3, I am stuck.

I have a multi checkbox html code chunck that I want to reuse : so I want it inside a fragment.

The no fragment code is working perfectly fine :

```
<div>
<h5 th:text="#{sg.multi-checkbox}"></h5>
<div class="field-box--wrapper">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            charset="utf8"
            th:src="@{/static/js/components/multichoice.js}"></script>
    <div class="field-box"
         th:each="attr, stat: ${allAttributs}"
         th:classappend="${!attr.nonModifiable && !dummy.isEdit()} ? 'field-hide'">
        <div th:if="${dummy.isEdit() || #arrays.contains(dummy.attributsCoches, attr.id)}">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   th:readonly="${attr.nonModifiable}"
                   th:field="${dummy.attributsCoches}"
                   th:value="${attr.id}"
            />
            <label th:for="${'attributsCoches' + __${stat.index + 1}__}"
                   th:text="${attr.nom}">label</label>
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I put the code in a thymeleaf fragment and I call it with `th:replace`. Since it's a fragment bound to be reused anywhere in the code, I can't keep the variable names I have used for my test development. 
It should be fine since the documentation explains how to do so "In order to create a more function-like mechanism for template fragments, fragments defined with th:fragment can specify a set of parameters:"  https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout

So I did :

Fragment

```
<div th:fragment="multichoix(mcTitle, mcAllChoices, mcIsEdit, mcCheckedChoices, mcCheckedChoicesName    )">
<h5 th:text="${mcTitle}"></h5>
<div class="field-box--wrapper">
    <script type="text/javascript"
            charset="utf8"
            th:src="@{/static/js/components/multichoice.js}"></script>
    <div class="field-box"
         th:each="attr, stat: ${mcAllChoices}"
         th:classappend="${!attr.nonModifiable && !mcIsEdit} ? 'field-hide'">
        <div th:if="${mcIsEdit || #arrays.contains(mcCheckedChoices, attr.id)}">
            <input type="checkbox"
                   th:readonly="${attr.nonModifiable}"
                   th:field="${mcCheckedChoices}"
                   th:value="${attr.id}"
            />
            <label th:for="${mcCheckedChoicesName + __${stat.index + 1}__}"
                   th:text="${attr.nom}">label</label>
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I call the fragment (from the same page, with the same model) with :

```
<!--   Fragmented multicheckbox       -->
        <div th:replace="styling/html-component/atomic/multichoix :: multichoix(mcTitle='a',
            mcAllChoices=${allAttributs},
            mcIsEdit=${dummy.isEdit()},
            mcCheckedChoices=${dummy.attributsCoches},
            mcCheckedChoicesName='attributsCoches')">
            multichoix fragment
        </div>
```

I got

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'mcCheckedChoices' available as request attribute

What am i missing ? Why

> dummy.attributsCoches

is not correctly processed ?

If I put `dummy.attributsCoches` in my fragment (so no intermediate variable), it obviously works.

dummy.attributsCoches is a private List with Getter & Setter.

Edit : doesn't work if I pass the argument without their names :

```
<!--   Fragmented multicheckbox       -->
        <div th:replace="styling/html-component/atomic/multichoix :: multichoix(
            'a',
            ${allAttributs},
            ${dummy.isEdit()},
            ${dummy.attributsCoches},
            'attributsCoches')">
            multichoix fragment
        </div>
```

Edit : so the issue is with `th:field` --as always with thymeleaf+spring ><

Comment: Is `th:field` a Spring extension to Thymeleaf? I don't recognize it (and I don't use Spring).

Comment: yes it is @andrewjames https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs More precisely it's a Thymeleaf processor for integrating with Spring

Comment: OK - thank you.  In that case, I am glad I deleted my irrelevant answer.